# Как сменить путь расположения базы данных и таблиц?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
MySQL 5,7 - x6,4
Open Server - последний

Хочу разместить базы данных на одном компьютере, а сервер на другом

В файле 
e:\srw\webopsrvr\modules\database\MySQL-5.7-x64\my.ini

Сменил пути
с
innodb_data_home_dir = "e:\srw\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64"

на
datadir = "\Server\e\srv\db\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64"

и
с
innodb_data_home_dir = "e:\srw\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64"

на
innodb_data_home_dir = "\Server\e\srv\db\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64"

после перезагрузки сервера пути возвращаются в исходное положение.

**Вопрос**
    1. Как сменить путь расположения базы данных и таблиц?
    2. Будут ли проблемы с работой MySql при таком размещении баз данных и таблиц (т.е. сервер на компе 1, а базы данных и таблицы на компе2)?

Comment: Практически уверен, что опенсервер сам восстанавливает конфиги из своих шаблонов при каждом запуске, и вы зря пытаетесь редактировать конечные файлы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итого мы имеем:

**1.** Чтобы сменить пути расположения баз данных MySQL нужно исправить файл конфига соответствующей версии MySQL, например **"MySQL-5.5_my.ini"**, файлы лежат по пути **"FolderInstall\OpenServer\userdata\config\"**. Все слеши пути в конфиг файле дублируются, как следствие, сетевой путь будет выглядеть так **datadir = "\\\\Server\\folder\\folder1"**. Проверено на OpenServer 5.2.2 и MySQL 5.5.

**2.** Проблемы расположения сервера на одной машине, а файлов баз данных на другой:

- Риск отключения файлового хранилища в процессе работы базы.
- Зависимость скорости чтения/записи от скорости сетевого соединения.
- Так как увеличивается количество машин для организации СУБД, соответственно уменьшается отказоустойчивость. (Например может рухнуть ОС на файлохранилище, может рухнуть ОС на машине, где установлен сервер, может пропасть сеть, может пропасть доступ к шаре, может быть перегрузка сетевого канала...и т.п.)

Comment: Со слешами вроде всё нормально... см .скрин.. http://prntscr.com/ee0lgx "только то, что если у Вас отлетит машина с хранилкой, на работающей MySQL" Компы в одной локальной сети. Что вы имеете ввиду? Допустим свет отрубится.. Это может будет источником повреждения данных?

Comment: Я имею ввиду то, что будет идти работа с таблицей, к примеру, а машина, где лежат базы, внезапно рухнет, отпадет сеть, да что угодно. Запись в таблицу, к примеру, не успеет из-за этого завершиться. Я же не знаю для чего Вы используете MySQL. А уточните тогда, когда вы меняете пути, сохраняете файл, my.ini, потом перезапускаете сервер, открываете файл my.ini и там снова дефолтные пути?

Comment: 1."Запись в таблицу, к примеру, не успеет из-за этого завершиться ..." Т.е. только одна(или несколько) запись(ей) или может вся таблица!!! прийти в негодность и не восстановится? Если одна (несколько) запись(ей), то я в принципе не вижу проблемы... Я пока тестирую... все компы в квартире, под рукой... После сбоя могу проверить попала запись или нет... 2."Я же не знаю для чего ..." Пока для фирмы: база клиентов и т.д... 3."и там снова дефолтные пути?" Да. PS.. Я пока осваиваю, поэтому прошу делать поправку на не компетентность вопросов. –

Comment: Хм, у меня установлен OpenServer 5.2.2, версия MySQL 5.5. Файл конфига называется MySQL-5.5_my.ini и находится в "c:\OpenServer\userdata\config\", Вы точно редактируете тот файл? Я сейчас сменил пути на другие, и все запустилось.

Comment: Ах да, забыл сказать, в конфиге сетевой путь выглядит примерно так: datadir = "\\\\<Server>\\Repository\\test". Вот так у меня сетевой путь заработал.

Comment: Всё сделал согласно ваших рекомендаций. Вроде пошла реакция, но не могу подключиться. См. скрин http://prntscr.com/eeibrb. Как подключиться?

Comment: Я бы все таки советовал скопировать имеющиеся файлы, в старой директории базы, в новую, сетевую, директорию, а те, которые MySQL создал сам, в сетевой шаре-удалить. Потому что у него в старой директории были системные базы данных,которые ему как бы нужны.Странно что у Вас таким образом запустилось,у меня OpenServer отказался запускаться пока я не скопировал таблицы в новую директорию.Но я проверил,после запуска базы,если флажок OpenServer-зеленый и системные базы скопированы в новую директорию,и вы запускаете MySQL менеджер на той же машине где установлен MySQL сервер, то по 127.0.0.1 пускает.

Comment: 1. Скопировал файлы "ib_logfile0", "ib_logfile1", "auto.cnf" из  "e:\srw\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64\"  в "\\Server\e\srv\db\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64\". 2 Перезапустил сервер. 3.Ошибка. См. скрин. "http://prntscr.com/eejmkj" . Правильно ли я всё сделал?

Comment: Я копировал все содержимое папки: 2 Папки "MySQL", "performance_schema" и 3 файла "ib_logfile0", "ib_logfile1", "ibdata1". Вы когда это скопируете, и перезапустите сервер, посмотрите в логах OpenServer, в вкладке "Отладка MySQL", что ему не хватило.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать ещё по этой теме http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635359/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B?noredirect=1#comment897143_635359