# Не создаются таблицы с именами начинающимися на цифры

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
MySQL 5,7 - x64
Open Server - последний
heidisql

MySQL расположен
e:\srw\MySQL-5.7-x64

Базы данных расположены в локальной сети
\Server\e\srv\db\webopsrvr\userdata\MySQL-5.7-x64\

**ОПИСАНИЕ**
Имя таблицы - **002_tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm1_ssl**

**-- Работает !!!**

```
CREATE TABLE tst_rb_mn_03.002_tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm1_ssl (id_tma_ssl INT, name_ssl TEXT, url_ssl TEXT );
```

**-- НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `002_tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm2_ssl` (
  `id_tma_ssl` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ssl` text,
  `url_ssl` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

При запуске данной команды появляется ошибка:
Ошибка SQL (1050): Table '`tst_rb_mn_03`.`002_tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm2_ssl`' already exists 
см. скрин.

```
INSERT INTO `002_tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm2_ssl` (`id_tma_ssl`, `name_ssl`, `url_ssl`) VALUES
    (4, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_1 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_1 '),
    (5, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_2 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_2 '),
    (6, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_3 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_3 ');
```

Имя таблицы - **tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm1_ssl**
**-- Работает**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm2_ssl` (
  `id_tma_ssl` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ssl` text,
  `url_ssl` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tst_01_vr_05_tbl_frm2_ssl` (`id_tma_ssl`, `name_ssl`, `url_ssl`) VALUES
    (4, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_1 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_1 '),
    (5, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_2 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_2 '),
    (6, 'name_ssl_05_tbl_zp_3 ', 'url_ssl_05_tbl_zp_3 ');
```

**Вопрос.**
Почему не создаются таблицы с именами начинающимися на цифры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странный баг с `if not exists`..

Comment: [offtop] Это уже не первый Ваш вопрос тут по проблемам, источником которых являются Ваши же ошибки при переносе каталога данных MySQL-сервера. Может, хватит бороться со следствиями? устраните, наконец, причину проблем. [/offtop]

Comment: @Akina Не понимаю вас... Вы имеете ввиду, что проблемы из-за того что каталог данных находится на другом компьютере?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что имеется серьёзная ошибка, в результате которой наблюдаются различные негативные эффекты. Источник этой ошибки - некорректно выполненный перенос каталогов месторасположения БД. В чём именно заключается ошибка - я понятия не имею. И да - то, что каталог БД расположен на другом хосте, вполне может быть частью ошибки. А может и не быть.

Comment: @Akina Блин... странно, что некоторые таблицы со скрипом импортировались... http://prntscr.com/efzjo6... Ладно... что-нибудь буду думать..

Comment: Да чего тут думать? снести нафиг конфиг сервера, сконфигурить заново, а потом корректно, строго в соответствии с мануалом, переместить дефолтный каталог данных, сами данные и таблеспейсы таблиц.